# How to expose a huge semantic graph (linked data) with a Datalog query interface

Tags: java, lucene, rdf, semantic-web, datalog

I have a huge semantic network, which has its specific Java API for querying the data (data stored in several [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) indices).

I want something more interactive (than Java programming) for querying it, like a [Datalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog) interface (or something else you can propose!), so that I can expose some relations, and then use [conjunctive queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_query) to extract the data I need, and everything is simple enough to write in a dummy interactive shell.

What are the possibilities out there to achieve this without reinventing big parts of the wheel? (i.e. without writing a datalog answering system by myself)

Is it better to integrate a Datalog frontend to extract the data (assuming such possibility exists)?
Or it is better to export the data in [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework), and use some available query/reasoning tool? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you said you do not necessarily want to do a lot of Java programming, but Jena's [general purpose rule engine](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#rules) includes a backward chaining rule reasoner which is a datalog engine.  The rule language is fairly simple, and you can extend it using Java if you want.  If you write a set of rules, you can provide them to a reasoner, bind the reasoner with an RDF model to produce an inference model, and you could then query that inference model using the Java API, or expose the inference model using a SPARQL endpoint (e.g., with Jena's [Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/)).

If the rules will not be static and fixed ahead of time, you might be able to extend the webabb interface to Fuskei to provide a “rule editing” section wherein you could provide rulesets and run them on the dataset.

Comment: I stumbled upon Jena...
what I don't understand is wether I have to dump my semantic net to an RDF file or something that could be read by Jena, or if I could integrate my thing via Java, and in this case, do the facts have to be all in memory or not?

let's say my semantic network API it's just a single class like this:

`    class SemanticNetwork {`
`        public Set<Person> getAllPersons() {...}`
`        public Set<Company> getAllCompanies() {...}`
`        public Set<Person> getPersonWorkingInCompany(Company c) {...}`
`        ....`
`    }`

how would you integrate this with Jena?

Comment: @mescalinum The title of your question used the term "linked data," which I expect that most people reading will assume means that your graph is RDF.  I did, anyways.  It doesn't sound like it would be all that hard to turn your data into an RDF model in Jena.  You could either do that and then serialize it (and read it back in later), or convert it in the same instance that serves up the web interface.